# mitmproxy response no content

Tags: python, mitmproxy

To make the problem simpler, let me explain the exact thing I did to reproduce the issue faster.

When you go to your own Github repository's traffic insight URL, let's say `https://github.com/yourusername/yournicerepo/graphs/traffic`, you will get a JSON formatted historical traffic data, like below, from the get requested URL `/yourusername/yournicerepo/graphs/traffic-data`. I found this using the Chrome dev tools network tab inspection. So, I can get the data using the dev tool, so why not I cannot get the same data using the software, mitmproxy. So I learnt about mitmproxy, wrote a script `_script.py` (as follows) and ran mitmproxy by `./mitmproxy --listen-port 8085 --scripts _script.py`.

The script should print the JSON but actually it printed me `b''`, and the HTTP GET log also showed me `[no content]`.

What is going on? Am I missing something?

(example json response)

```json
{"counts":[{"bucket":1625529600,"total":0,"unique":0},{"bucket":1625443200,"total":1,"unique":1},{"bucket":1625356800,"total":6,"unique":4}, ..
```

(_script.py)

```py
def response(flow):

    if("graphs/traffic-data" in flow.request.url):
        print("flow.response.content")
        print(flow.response.content)
```

Comment: This looks generally right. Do you perhaps encounter HTTP caching? https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-features/#anticache

Comment: nice. I solved the issue by the `--anticache ` option. thanks.